# ReferenceError: $ is not defined on local machine but works fine on server?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

All,
  I recently setup a laptop for ROR development.  Everything seemed to be fine until I served a site (development mode).  The firefox dev console shows:

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
$(document).ready(function(){
```

All I did was clone this repo, bundle install, serve...  This APP is working on many other machines and servers so I know it has to be a local environment issue; I just can't seem to find it!

I've looked through other posts, searches, websites and have not found a solution as most other solutions are related to source order, spelling, reference errors,..etc.

My next step is to compare gems/bundles/sets from working machines to the new development laptop.  I'm hoping for some reason this machine is pulling a different jquery gem?

I'm running debian linux using RVM with mainly standard configurations

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Thank you

**** UPDATE ****
application.js is loading but it does not contain the jquery library.  I'll start looking at the asset pipeline and the config/environment files; however I believe the solution should not include modifications to any source files as this application has worked on several machines and environments.  I need to verify working ruby, rails, gems,...etc. versions compared to the machine that is not working.

I'm using jquery-rails and asset-sync gems in this app.  In development mode everything should be served from local libraries... another place I'll check.

Thoughts?

Thank you!

Comment: most probably, you refered the jquery online and your local system doesnt have internet connection..??

Comment: @AnoopJoshi yup seems to be like that. OP should look for local jQuery library or connect the system to the internet.

Comment: Check jQuery path in network tab, expected one?

Comment: if you are using google CDN (`//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js`), it doesnt work locally.

Comment: I'm successfully loading local application.js (seeing proper response).  I did see I have two jquery-rails gems loaded (version 3.0.4 & 3.1) and am going to look for other gems / libraries causing a conflict?